# Sending and retrieving an image through socket programming in python

Tags: python, image, sockets

I attempted to write code to send an image to the server which modifies it and sends it back the client. I send the image in chunks of length 1024. The idea was to do some image editing using Opencv on the server side and then send the image back to the client. However, my client code halts execution each time just before receiving the image. I have a feeling that this is a synchornization issue. The client calls recv before the server creates the image file (Client.py).
My Server side code:

```
from socket import *

serverPort = 12000
serverSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
serverSocket.bind(('', serverPort))
serverSocket.listen(1)
print("Server is ready to service...")

while 1:
    connectionSocket, addr = serverSocket.accept()
    res = ''
    while 1:
        t = connectionSocket.recv(1024)
        if not t:
            break
        res += t
    g = open("Client.jpg", "wb")
    g.write(res)
    g.close()
    print("Image received and recreated")


    f = open("Client.jpg", "rb")
    #print(len(f))
    print("Sending image data...")
    while 1:
        print("In while")
        #data = f.read(1024)
        if not data:
            break
        connectionSocket.send(data)
        print("Data sent:"+str(len(data)))

    connectionSocket.close()
```

The client side code:

```
    from socket import *
import time

serverName = 'localhost'
serverPort = 12000

clientSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
clientSocket.connect((serverName, serverPort))

Image = open("BG.jpg", "rb")

print("Sending image data...")
while 1:
    data = Image.read(1024)
    if not data:
        break
    clientSocket.send(data)
    #print(len(data))

print("Data has been sent!")
print("-------------------")
time.sleep(3)
print("Receving data")

res = ''
while 1:
    print("in while")
    t = clientSocket.recv(1024)
    print(len(t))
    if not t:
        break
    res += t

g = open("Response.jpg", "wb")
g.write(res)
g.close()

clientSocket.close()
```

Please let me know if I should provide any more information.

The output of both the sides isn't much. 
Output on Client Side:

```
Sending image data...
Data has been sent!
-------------------
Receving data
in while
```

Output on Server Side:

```
Server is ready to service...
Image received and recreated
Sending image data...
In while
```

This is the output after I let the code run for about two minutes before interrupting it.

Comment: could you post output of the program as well please?

Comment: I have done so.

Answer (score 0):

It is weird that the server has been able to write `Image received and recreated` before the client has ended, because your code contains a loop reading until the socket is shut down or closed:

```
while 1:
    t = connectionSocket.recv(1024)
    if not t:    # t should be empty only when the socket is shut down or closed...
        break
    res += t
```

In that kind of exchange, the server cannot know when the client has finished sending data. You should use a protocol to say that. For example, you could send first the length of the file and then the data, and the server would know that when it has received the correct count of bytes it can do its own processing.

Alternatively, as you have only one transmission on each side, you could shut down the socket for sending first from the client, then from the server, but it is not the correct use of `shut` that is normally used at a lower level to set up a graceful shutdown.